# Return a map in Java JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a table called rating as follows:

```
id | score | article_id
```

score can be from 1 to 5.

I want to have a single query that returns the number of scored-5s, scored-4s, scored-3s, scored-2s, scored-1.  Because I don't want to run 5 queries for this task.
It would be convenient if the query can be returned a map like:

- The key is the score from 1 to 5
- The value if the corresponding numbers of that score

Is there any way (or similar) to achieve that?
I'm using Java JPA, MySQL 5.x

Comment: Which JPA implementation are you using? There is no standard way to return a map as a result type in JPA. It may nevertheless be available as a provider specific feature. For example, EclipseLink does support it - `query.setHint(QueryHints.RESULT_TYPE, ResultType.Map);`.

Comment: I use JPA implementation in Play framework which uses Hibernate's implementation

Comment: I think you are going to have to settle for a `List<Object[]>` query result.  You can convert this to a `Map` if you'd like but with only 5 keys I see no need.  Either of the answers given should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create normal query that return type is Object[] like:

`Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select count(r), r.score from Rating r group by r.score");`

then:
`List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();` 
and you can iterate over it and get result from `results[0]` and `results[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `CriteriaQuery`:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Rating> rating = query.from(Rating.class);
query.multiselect(rating.get("score"), cb.count(rating)).groupBy(rating.get("score"));

List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
System.out.println("score | count\n-----------");
for(Object[] object : results){
    System.out.println(object[0] + " | " + object[1]);
}
```

This assumes that the name of your rating entity class is `Rating`.